# разработка схемы ip-адресации

Tags: ip

Можете, пожалуйста, помочь в разработке схемы адресации. Вот у меня 4 филиала по 18,9,9,7 устройств. я беру диапазон 192.168.0.0/26 первому филиалу назначению диапазон 192.168.0.0/27, второму 192.168.0.32/28, третьему 192.168.0.48/28 и **вопрос с 4 диапазоном**. Какой он будет его диапазон IP адресов?

Comment: Зачем так сложно. отдайте на каждую подсеть по классу C: 192.168.0/24, 192.168.1/24 и т.п. А то сами потом замучаетесь вспоминать по последней цифре где она у вас.Да и подсети имеют свойство со временем расти, а менять план нумерации по всей сети из за перевеса в одном филиале ...

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Правильное распределение адресов делается следующим образом.

**Филиал 1.** 18 устройств. 16 адресов мало, 32 достаточно. Отдаём на подсеть пять последних бит. Получаем подсеть `192.168.0.0/27`, т.е адреса `192.168.0.0-192.168.0.31`. `192.168.0.0` - адрес подсети, `192.168.0.31` - broadcast.

**Филиал 2.** 9 устройств. 8 адресов мало, 16 достаточно. Подсети даём четыре последних бита, т.е. выбираем `192.168.0.32/28`. Диапазон `192.168.0.32-192.168.0.47`. Адрес подсети - `192.168.0.32`, broadcast `192.168.0.47`.

**Филиал 3.** То же, что и филиал 2. Подсеть `192.168.0.48/28` (`192.168.0.48-192.168.0.63`). Адрес подсети `192.168.0.48`, broadcast - `192.168.0.63`.

**Филиал 4.** 7 устройств. Тут чуть посложнее. Вроде бы, 8 адресов достаточно. Но один уйдёт на адрес подсети, другой на широковещание. Поэтому придётся брать 16. Подсеть `192.168.0.64/28` (`192.168.0.64-192.168.0.79`). Адрес подсети `192.168.0.64`, broadcast - `192.168.0.79`.

Здесь не учитывалось, что если подсетям нужно между собой общаться, то добавится ещё одно устройство - маршрутизатор, которому нужен дополнительный адрес. Впрочем, в данном случае адресов достаточно и маршрутизатору хватит.

Если же это не учебное задание, а реальное, то для упрощения администрирования и для получения возможности безболезненного масштабирования, лучше для филиалов взять подсети `192.168.x.0/24`, где `x` меняется от `1` до `4` и означает номер филиала. В такой адресации разобраться будет проще.